# Inverse Kinematics 5DOF - general approach - Wrong solution MATLAB

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, inverse-kinematics, matlab, dynamixel

[image]Can anyone name a good source for a general approach (cookbook-like) for the inverse kinematics regarding a 5-DOF?

[The paper by De Xu et al.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.66.5101&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is aiming for a general approach, but it doesn't work for my code. Maybe you could check that one as well?!

I am new to MATLAB, the code is no masterpiece:

**Parameter used:**

a=[0 82 93 55 95 0];

d=[47 0 0 0 0 10];

alpha=[90 0 0 0 0 0];

theta=[15 30 40 -90 -15 0];

**Result for Theta 1-5:**

1. 5,080
2. 38,029
3. 75,947
4. -90,247
5. 20,719

   EDIT: 
   The results 1-5 mentioned above are the one the code gave me. But those are wrong, because:

Position of TCP (taken form the Forward Kinematics):

px= -5.7853

py=  5.7606

pz=  25.908

Position of TCP (using the calculating values for Theta 1-5):

px=  47.0

py= -151.0

pz=  43.9430

All values in degrees.
I am using 5 servos by Dynamixel ax-12a.

```
a=[0 82 93 55 95 0];
d=[47 0 0 0 0 10];
alpha=[90 0 0 0 0 0];
theta=[15 30 -90 0 45 0];
rad=57.295779513082;

T01=[cos(theta(1)),-sin(theta(1))*cos(alpha(1)),sin(theta(1))*sin(alpha(1)),a(1)*cos(theta(1));
    sin(theta(1)),cos(theta(1))*cos(alpha(1)),-cos(theta(1))*sin(alpha(1)),a(1)*sin(theta(1));
    0,sin(alpha(1)),cos(alpha(1)),d(1);
    0,0,0,1];
T12=[cos(theta(2)),-sin(theta(2))*cos(alpha(2)),sin(theta(2))*sin(alpha(2)),a(2)*cos(theta(2));
    sin(theta(2)),cos(theta(2))*cos(alpha(2)),-cos(theta(2))*sin(alpha(2)),a(2)*sin(theta(2));
    0,sin(alpha(2)),cos(alpha(2)),d(2);
    0,0,0,1];
T23=[cos(theta(3)),-sin(theta(3))*cos(alpha(3)),sin(theta(3))*sin(alpha(3)),a(3)*cos(theta(3));
    sin(theta(3)),cos(theta(3))*cos(alpha(3)),-cos(theta(3))*sin(alpha(3)),a(3)*sin(theta(3));
    0,sin(alpha(3)),cos(alpha(3)),d(3);
    0,0,0,1];
T34=[cos(theta(4)),-sin(theta(4))*cos(alpha(4)),sin(theta(4))*sin(alpha(4)),a(4)*cos(theta(4));
    sin(theta(4)),cos(theta(4))*cos(alpha(4)),-cos(theta(4))*sin(alpha(4)),a(4)*sin(theta(4));
    0,sin(alpha(4)),cos(alpha(4)),d(4);
    0,0,0,1];

T45=[cos(theta(5)),-sin(theta(5))*cos(alpha(5)),sin(theta(5))*sin(alpha(5)),a(5)*cos(theta(5));
    sin(theta(5)),cos(theta(5))*cos(alpha(5)),-cos(theta(5))*sin(alpha(5)),a(5)*sin(theta(5));
    0,sin(alpha(5)),cos(alpha(5)),d(5);
    0,0,0,1];

T56=[cos(theta(6)),-sin(theta(6))*cos(alpha(6)),sin(theta(6))*sin(alpha(6)),a(6)*cos(theta(6));
    sin(theta(6)),cos(theta(6))*cos(alpha(6)),-cos(theta(6))*sin(alpha(6)),a(6)*sin(theta(6));
    0,sin(alpha(6)),cos(alpha(6)),d(6);
    0,0,0,1];

T06=T01*T12*T23*T34*T45*T56;        %transformation matrix
inv_T01=inv(T01);
inv_T12=inv(T12);
inv_T23=inv(T23);
inv_T56=inv(T56);
T05=T06*inv_T56;
%needed for theta4 and theta5
Inverse=inv_T23*inv_T12*inv_T01*T06*inv_T56;
T_4_5=T34*T45;

N=T06(1:3,1);
nx=N(1,1);
ny=N(2,1);
nz=N(3,1);
O=T06(1:3,2);
ox=O(1,1);
oy=O(2,1);
oz=O(3,1);
A=T06(1:3,3);
ax=A(1,1);
ay=A(2,1);
az=A(3,1);
P=T06(1:3,4); %comapre to (17) in paper
px=P(1,1);
py=P(2,1);
pz=P(3,1);
px_2=T05(1,4);
py_2=T05(2,4);


%theta1
help1=px_2;               %not sure
help2=py_2;                 %not sure
help3=(px_2*(-1));         %not sure
help4=(py_2*(-1));         %not sure

theta11=atan2(help2,help1);
theta12=atan2(help4,help3);     %using this
theta1=atan2(py,px);            %most common way

%Theta2
B1=(az*d(6)-pz+d(1));
B2=(sqrt((-ax*d(6)+px).^2+(-ay*d(6)+py).^2))-a(1); %taking only positive value, alternative: [1 -1]*sqrt
B3=((B1.^2+B2.^2+a(2).^2-d(4).^2));
%auxiliary angle
beta=(atan2(B2,B1));
root=((a(2)*a(2))*sqrt(B1.^2+B2.^2));

theta21=(asin(B3/root)-beta);%works best
theta22=pi-theta21;

%theta3

theta3=atan2(B1-a(2)*sin(theta21),B2-a(2)*cos(theta21))-theta21; %using theta21 is close to determined angle BUT still far away from acceptable

%theta4
%auxiliary
OX=(ox*cos(theta1).*sin(theta21+theta3));
OY=(oy*sin(theta1).*sin(theta21+theta3));
OZ=(oz*cos(theta21+theta3));
theta4=atan2(-OX-OY-OZ,ox.*sin(theta1)*oy.*cos(theta1));%as in the case

%theta5
%auxiliary
NX=(nx*cos(theta1).*cos(theta21+theta3));
NY=(ny*sin(theta1).*cos(theta21+theta3));
NZ=(nz*sin(theta21+theta3));
AX=(ax*cos(theta1).*cos(theta21+theta3));
AY=(ay*sin(theta1).*sin(theta21+theta3));

theta5=atan2(NX+NY-NZ,-AX+AY-az*sin(theta21+theta3));%as in the case

theta12*rad
theta21*rad
theta3*rad
theta4*rad
theta5*rad

enter code here
```

Comment: Apart from theta2 it seems to work. Someone ones how to calculate theta2? thanks

Comment: would you please send the paper link?(it is broken).and did using radians instead if degree solved the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never saw a conversion between degrees in radians in your code, so that would be the number one problem to fix. All of your transform matrices are using `sin` and `cos` terms, which **only accept values in radians**, and using them with values in degrees. I'm a bit busy at the moment but I'll go over the code in more detail later today.

Comment: Overlooked this one all the time....but still. my coding "skills" lack the right solution. Appreciate your effort, Chuck.